# Record one2one call as a single video Kurento

Tags: video, webrtc, kurento

I am trying to create a video calling web application using kurento with video recording option.

I have set up kurento media server and service added with their example as follows,

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-recording
git checkout 6.2.1
mvn compile exec:java
```

I need to record the video as a single video file,is it possible?
in the above example gives video with remote side only

Comment: Each MediaPipeline object can have a RecorderEndpoint attached to it.  You can combine the outputs into a single stream with a Composite object.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/kXZ3CGo5WOA